# docker git and pull setup

Tags: github, docker, verification

I have a repo set up in github to pull into a docker build. I want to add my keys so I can connect to git but I'm unsuccessfully adding the key file. The error:

```
id_rsa: no such file or directory
```

The file exists in the dir specified in the Dockerfile. I tried linking my local file to the docker enviroment with ln command but I get the same error. Here's the docker statements:

```
 RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && ln -s /Users/e002678/.ssh /root/.ssh
 RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
 RUN adduser git
 RUN ssh-keyscan github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

In a variant attempt I tried adding a shared volume with the same results:

```
 VOLUME ["/Users/e002678/.ssh"]
 ADD /Users/e002678/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker [ADD](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) only works relative to the Dockerfile directory.

For `ADD /Users/e002678/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa` to work, you need a source directory like:

```
$ ls
./Dockerfile
./Users/e002678/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

**Tip** `ADD` copies files "with metadata," i.e. files are copied with the exact same user id, same group id, and same permissions. So explicitly chown/chmod keys after adding them:

```
ADD ./Users/e002678/.ssh/id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chown root: /root/.ssh/id_rsa && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

**Pro Tip** Docker `ADD` creates any needed directories in a path, so `RUN mkdir` instructions are unnecessary.

Comment: Are you saying we can't use full paths in the usual way? It must be in the `Dockerfile`'s root directory or sub-folder?

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of getting this spike completed I used a workaround to grab a public zip of the repo. In prod I will want to access the private repo but for the sake of time I did this:

```
RUN wget https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/master.zip
RUN ls master.zip | xargs -n1 unzip
```

This gets the files I need to continue but it's not what I really need. I'm still interested in a solution for the original post. Thanks!